# Using redirect 301 or rewriterule in htaccess to redirect and take a php variable with you

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I think my question is quite simple but I've been banging my head against the wall for the past few hours.

I have my website using rewriterule to ensure messy path names with php variables are now nice and tidy(I've removed [http://www] from my examples because the system thinks I am putting links and won't let me).

So somebody comes to my site at mysite.co.uk/my-product-P1.html the website will know to post mysite.co.uk/product.php?id=1 to the server.

But I also want to tidy it up the other way around. If an old customer or an old link uses the pathname mysite.co.uk/product.php?id=1 then I want it to return mysite.co.uk/my-product-P1.html instead even though the old pathname will actually still work. I don't want customers accessing the same page from different pathnames.

How do I do this and will it create a loop? On another website I have it working using:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^product\.php$ product-P1.html? [R=301,L]
```

But on that site there are only around 10 products so I'm able to write these lines for each products. On my other site I have hundreds of products so this isn't practical and I need to do it automatically.

Hopefully this makes sense. I have read through other posts and can't find my solution so apologies if this is clearly explained somewhere else.

Comment: The only way you would get a loop is if both rewrite rules are redirects.  In your case they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I do this and will it create a loop?

The rules that you have (on the site with 10 products) need to match against the actual request as opposed to the URI:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /product\.php\?id=([^\ &]+)
RewriteRule ^ /product-P%1.html? [R=301,L]
```

But you're better off doing this in your php script rather than enumerating all the products in the htaccess file:

> On my other site I have hundreds of products so this isn't practical and I need to do it automatically

You can't do that using only mod_rewrite. You'll need to script that in your `product.php` script. The `product.php` script will need to check the `$_SERVER'[REQUEST_URI']` php variable, and see if it starts with: `/product.php`.

If it does, then you know someone accessed the php script directly, and you'll need to fetch the product name using the id passed in `$_GET['id']`, then redirect to the product name + `"-P$_GET['id'].html"`.

The htaccess file and mod_rewrite won't know the mapping between product IDs and product names, so you need to do this in your php script (which does have access to this mapping).

Comment: thanks. I didn't need to use the php as it was quicker to do the 10 of so manual redirects on the one site. For the other using the rewritecond worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need this additional rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+product\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /product-P%1.html? [R=302,L]
```